# func_get_args for javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I get all the function arguments in javascript inside an array?

```
function(a, b, c){

 // here how can I get an array of all the arguments passed to this function
 // like [value of a, value of b, value of c]
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You use the `arguments` object (it's not an *array* as stated in other answers, it has some other interesting properties, see 
[here](http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/01/18/javascripts-arguments-object-and-beyond/)).
It is automatically created in the function's scope when you define the function itself.

```
functon bar(arg1,arg2,arg3,...)
{
     console.log(arguments[2]); // gets "arg2"'s value
}
```

There is another form as a property of the function object:

```
function foo(a,b,c,d) {
}

var args = foo.arguments;
```

but, though supported, it has become deprecated.

Answer (score 11):

You want the [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments) <strike>array</strike> object.

```
function x(a, b, c){
    console.log(arguments); // [1,2,3]
}

x(1,2,3);
```

**UPDATE**: `arguments` isn't actually an array, it's an "Array-like object".  To make a true array, do this:

```
var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
```

Comment: It's an *object*, not an array, though enumerable.

Comment: Thanks a lot for editing, I thought it is worth to show that as an object, other interesting properties are available :) Upvoting for the make-it-an-array part.

Comment: @Cranio: I also figured I should add that, because if you try to call array methods on it (like `slice`) it won't work.

Answer (score 5):

Access the arguments object.

```
function(a, b, c){
    console.log(arguments);
    console.log(arguments[0]);
    console.log(arguments[1]);
    console.log(arguments[2]);
}
```

Comment: thanks. do you know how can I drop the first argument from the array? I tried with arguments.slice(1) but it says that method doesnt exist

Comment: The arguments object is not an array, it doesn't have a `slice` method. Fixed my answer.

Comment: @Alex: You need to convert it to an array first.  `var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);`.

Comment: If you always have to remove the first element, use `shift()` instead of `slice(n)`

Answer (score 5):

Use arguments:

```
for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
  // arguments[i]
}
```